# Can't show toast if app is off

Tags: android, android-alarms

I'm trying to create an alarm in android. I have a toast, but it works only if application is running at this moment. I need to have toast/notification even if the screen is off or apllication doesn't run. Where am I wrong?

MainActivity:

```
public void setTime() {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK,
                    onTimeSetListener,
                    calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                    true);
            timePickerDialog.setTitle(""); 
            timePickerDialog.show();
    }

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
    };
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Вставай!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

In Manifest I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
```

Comment: I think you need to use a system notification, not a Toast. As far as I know, the Toast can't be used unless the app is in the foreground.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333600/android-display-toast-even-the-app-is-closed

Comment: @AaronFranco Thanks for explanation. I don't need exactly the `Toast`, it was an example. So, how to create an alarm notification? Not in notification bar, but on the main screen. With delay and cancel actions. Can you help me with it?