# Show toast message when application close from background in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-devtools

Even if you remove the app from the background in flutter, a toast message should come every 1 second. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android display Toast even the app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333600/android-display-toast-even-the-app-is-closed)

Comment: this is for android not for flutter

Comment: It doesn't matter as the output remains same, any app showing Toast when it's in background is bad UX and Notifications should be preferred instead.

Also, no you can't show toast when app is closed as `context` is required.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run a background service run timer every second if the user removes the app from the background and displays toast every second
check this
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes